# Android MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage works on KitKat only after using camera app to take a picture

Tags: android, mediastore, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an app in which the user draws an image using Canvas and Bitmap. When the user wishes to save the image I use MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage.

On an Android 4.3 or earlier device or AVD it works.

On an Android 4.4 AVD it works.

On an Android 4.4 device it fails with a FileNotFound exception appearing only in DDMS. HOWEVER, if I then go to the Android 4.4 devices camera app and take one picture, then go back to my app and save my image IT WORKS!

Seems like a bug to me. Anyone have any ideas?

Best, Paul

Comment: Could it be that the folder structure where images are stores is not created yet and is properly created by the Camera app?  Does seem like a bug in the .InsertImage logic, might attempt to mkdirs() that path (if you're allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there's the folder /sdcard/0/emulated/DICM/Camera. In Android4.4(Kitkat), 3rd party app doesn't create the DCIM/Camera folder. It seems like a bug.

[related Google's commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/92013781ab1573eee3d5d75682f320fe3a6076f2%5E!/)